# How to only read first X bytes of a web page using Scrapy/Twisted?

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy, twisted

The information i need is at the very top of a page.
Is it possible to terminate a Scrapy download after a certain number of bytes to save bandwidth?

Comment: See this relevant [gist](https://gist.github.com/stav/4356269).

Comment: that looks like it still downloads the full page